# Accessing Array with space in key Value

Tags: array, key

I have an array in this format

```
$dataArray = "array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Field Val' =>'val1',
    'Field Val2' =>'val2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Field Val' =>'val1',
    'Field Val2' =>'val2'
  )";
```

I want to iterate this array and return it in the format below

```
foreach($dataArray as $data) {
  $newArray = ['name'=>val1,'address'=>val2];
}
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: that's not an array, that's a string. and not even one that you convert easily.

Comment: double quote also there or you just added?

Comment: also "name" and "address" ca not be found in the given string

Comment: this code is all over the place. it's not valid PHP. fix this first

Answer (score 1):

## that's not an array, that's a string.

And another problem is, that it's not even valid json nor valid php code.

you have to fix this first.

But the much better solution is to figure out were that string comes from, because it obviously was an array before you probably called `var_dump` on it.

you probably want this:

```
$dataArray = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Field Val' =>'val1',
    'Field Val2' =>'val2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Field Val' =>'val1',
    'Field Val2' =>'val2'
  )
);
```

### valid php as string

you have to `eval()` to create the code in your string. and then you have an array.

### If you would work with strings in json notation this would be the preffered way:

you can use `$dataArray = json_decode($dataArray, true);` to convert it to an actual array.

The much cleaner way is to inject `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` and use `serialize($data)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `array_merge` in your example try this one :

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
} 

$dataArray = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Field1' =>'val1',
    'Field2' =>'val2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Field3' =>'val1',
    'Field4' =>'val2'
  ));

  echo"<pre/>";
  print_r(array_flatten($dataArray));
```